# jquery sortable helper wrong position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, helper

I'm using jquery sortable to sort elements across multiple sections(containers).

I have a custom helper for the sortable item.

```
$('.section').sortable({
    handle: '.handle',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    connectWith: '.section',
    scrollSpeed: 10,
    helper: () => {
       return (`
           <div style="width:25px;height:25px;background-color:black;border-radius:50%;">
           </div>
       `);
    },
});
```

When I start dragging a row the helper jumps to the left side of the page. It should have been located at the mouse pointer. I have a feeling that this is happening because of margin 0px in the row div. Please help me fix it. Here is my html code.

```
<style>
    .section {
        padding: 40px 0px;
        
    }
    .row {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 1080px;
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .handle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        z-index: 9;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .placeholder {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 1080px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```